# How to load multiple files (same schema) from LOCAL into a table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, multiprocessing, bq

I have multi-files in a folder in my local machine. And every file has the same schema. how can I upload those files into BQ in one line cli?
I tried this:

`bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --ignore_unknown_values temp.test_load ./* ./schema.json`

But I got this error
`Too many positional args, still have...`(and continues with the name of all files in the folder)

But when I specife the file name, it uploads it into BQ without any error:

`bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --ignore_unknown_values temp.test_load ./file_1.ndjson.gz ./schema.json`  (this one is working)

How can I make multi uploads from local?

Answer (score 1):

When loading data from local files to BigQuery, *files can only be loaded individually* as the Wildcards and comma-separated lists are [not supported](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#limitations-local-files) for loading data from local files.

The [Wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#load-wildcards) are only supported if you are loading data from Cloud Storage to BigQuery, provided all the files share a common base-name.